# How do get the first occurrence of a char in Substring

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the first occurrence in my substring start point:

```
string dir = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + "\\App_GlobalResources\\";

foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.resx"))
{
    ddlResources.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = file.Substring(firstoccuranceof("."), file.LastIndexOf(".")), Value = file });
}
```

if I do file.Substring(file.IndexOf("."), file.LastIndexOf(".")) I get an error

Comment: Can you give a specific example, for a given string, what do you want to get? Example: If string was `"Hello_world.jpg"` what should be the result?

Comment: You have a syntax error, namely use of '{' '}' as in : new ListItem {...}.  Also, why are you assigning Text = and Value = ... they don't do anything, and lastly you probably mean to get the name of the file without .resx extension and you get that using: file.Substring(0, fileLastIndexOf("."))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To answer your actual question - you can use `string.IndexOf` to get the first occurrence of a character.  Note that you'll need to subtract this value from your `LastIndexOf` call, since `Substring`'s second parameter is the number of characters to fetch, not a start and end index.

However... Instead of parsing the names, you can just use [Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) to get the filename directly.

Comment: could you show my what you mean cos i've tried it this way file.Substring(file.IndexOf("."), file.LastIndexOf("."))

Comment: @KDM What are you trying to achieve?  You probably need `file.Substring(file.IndexOf("."), file.LastIndexOf(".")-file.IndexOf("."))` - but GetFilenameWithoutExtension may be better here...

Comment: +1 for not just saying how they "should do it instead", but for answering the given question _and also_ providing an alternate method

Answer (score 18):

First occurence

```
String.IndexOf('.')
```

Last occurence

```
String.LastIndexOf('.')
```

Comment: What error ? May we know to actually see what fails for you ?

Answer (score 7):

Use `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` string methods to get index of first and last occurrence of "search" string. You may use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension()`,         `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`, and `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` methods to parse the path.

For instance,

```
string file = @"c:\csnet\info.sample.txt";
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file));           //c:\csnet
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));                //info.sample.txt
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));//info.sample
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file));               //.txt
```

Comment: I think this is what he needs, to get the filename without path and extension.

Comment: Yes. He is doing this by round the way. He could have even used a split and got the strings rather than substring for this task. This answer is best for his task

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your particular case you are NOT trying to get IndexOf... Instead you need to use 0 because you are trying to create a key based on filename if understand correctly:

```
`ddlResources.Items.Add(new ListItem(file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf(".")), file ));`
```

Also, you have '{}' in there as in new ListItem { ... } which is also going to cause a syntax error... Anyhow have a look..

Answer (score 1):

file.IndexOf(".")

Should get you the first occurence of ".". Otherwise it will return -1 if not found.

Answer (score 0):

Because the original question is marked with the [regex] tag, I'll provide the following solution, however the best answer for simple parsing of paths using .NET is not by regex.

```
//extracts "filename" from "filename.resx"
string name = Regex.Match("filename.resx", @"^(.*)\..+?$").Groups[1].Value;
```

Use an answer that relies on the `Path` class instead, for simplicity.  Other answers contain that info.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!)

Using a string variable type

```
int index = str.IndexOf(@"\");
```

"C:\Users\somebody\Desktop\aFolder\someFile"

[https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31938&seqNum=12#:~:text=To%20find%20the%20first%20or,string%20you%20are%20searching%20for](https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31938&seqNum=12#:%7E:text=To%20find%20the%20first%20or,string%20you%20are%20searching%20for).